# Change Cursor On Mouse Wheel Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

### New jQuery Custom Scroll

I'm working on a new jQuery custom scroll as others I have come across out there are not up-to-date with the latest version of jQuery. I'm right down to the basics at this moment of time.

I'm trying to get the mouse wheel button click to trigger events and change the cursor however this is proving to have some difficulties involved;

```js
$(document).on({
 mousedown: function(e) {
  "use strict";
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if (e.which === 2) {
   $('html,body').css('cursor','all-scroll');
   $(window).data('isDown', true).data('mPosX', e.pageX).data('mPosY', e.pageY);
  }
 },
 mouseup: function(e) {
  "use strict";
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if (e.which === 2) {
   $(window).data('isDown', false);
  }
 },
 mousemove: function(e) {
  "use strict";
  if ($(window).data('isDown')) {
   var CmPosX = e.pageX,
    CmPosY = e.pageY,
    mPosX  = $(window).data('mPosX'),
    mPosY  = $(window).data('mPosY');
   
   console.log('Original X: '    + mPosX +
    ', New X: '       + CmPosX +
    ' | Original Y: ' + mPosY +
    ', New Y: '       + CmPosY
   );
  }
 }  
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
 "use strict";
 switch(e.keyCode)     {
        case 32:
            console.log("Spacebar pressed");
        break;
  case 33:
            console.log("Page Up pressed");
        break;
  case 34:
            console.log("Page Down pressed");
        break;
        case 37:
            console.log("Left Arrow pressed");
        break;
        case 38:
            console.log("Up Arrow pressed");
        break;
  case 39:
            console.log("Right Arrow pressed");
        break;
  case 40:
            console.log("Down Arrow pressed");
        break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### How can I get the cursor to change on press?

I've tried a test to get the cursor to change upon clicking the mouse wheel button by implementing `$('html,body').css('cursor','all-scroll');` into my script, however this only changes after you release the mouse wheel button.

### How do I set the cursor to scroll?

In Google Chrome, on pages you can scroll, the mouse wheel upon pressing will change and change again upon keeping it held and move in each compass direction (ie; North, North-East, East...).

I know this part requires checking the current position against the original position however as for these types of cursors, I cannot find them.

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to change the pointer globally, all you can do is add cursor styles to elements, and if that doesn't work I have no idea what will? Maybe some trickery with `setCapture` or pointer events ?

Comment: Currently, I am struggling to acquire a copy of the cursor set Google Chrome uses for reference to the above questions asked. `$('html,body').css('cursor','all-scroll');` does work to change the cursor, however regardless of where I have attempted to place this code, it seems to appear only upon release of the mouse wheel button.